# How can I change the color a select depending on the chosen result?

Tags: html, css

I have a select and I need the background to change depending on the chosen answer.

```html
<select>
  <option value="always">Always</option>
  <option value="tagged">Only when tagged</option>
  <option value="never">Never</option>
</select>
```

Comment: please share code which you tried from your side for changing color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe you can do this with CSS only and without JavaScript (or server-side rendering).

There are many ways to do this with JavaScript. Here is a very vanilla one ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wtd1f9r/)):

```
<script>
  function valueChanged(val) {
    var elem = document.querySelector('select'); // or whatever element needs to change background color
    var color;
    if (val === 'always') {
        color = 'green'; // or whatever color
    }
    else if (val === 'tagged') {
      color = 'yellow';
    }
    else if (val === 'never') {
      color = 'red';    
    }
    if (color) {
      elem.style['background-color'] = color;
    }
  }
</script>
<select onChange="valueChanged(this.value)">
  <option value="always">Always</option>
  <option value="tagged">Only when tagged</option>
  <option value="never">Never</option>
</select>
```

Or with CSS (but still JavaScript) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4dm63fq/)):

```
<style>
  .always {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .tagged {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .never {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
<script>
  function valueChanged(val) {
    var elem = document.querySelector('select'); // or whatever element needs to change background color
    elem.className = val;
  }
</script>
<select onChange="valueChanged(this.value)">
  <option value="always">Always</option>
  <option value="tagged">Only when tagged</option>
  <option value="never">Never</option>
</select>
```

Comment: He asked for css though.

Comment: Would this be even possible with css, would seem redundant and more complex then using javascript?

Comment: I don't think so off hand. Parent selectors have been an ask for like a decade but I fell out of the front-end space a while ago, so I'm not up to date on the latest.

Comment: Thanks @AlienWebguy, missed that "CSS" at first as it was only in the tag. Updated clarifying the answer is not CSS-only, but an answer leveraging CSS + JavaScript is also included.

Answer (score 1):

Add class with option value to select tag

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option value="always">Always</option>
  <option value="tagged">Only when tagged</option>
  <option value="never">Never</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.color-always {
    background-color: #5a5a8d;
}
.color-tagged {
    background-color: #ecb102;
}
.color-never {
    background-color: #d6f843;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('select').on('change', function(ev) {
    var select = $(this);
    var value = select.val().toLowerCase();
    var className = 'color-' + value;
    $(this).attr('class', '').addClass(className);
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/colorswall/xpvt214o/999801/

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="always" color='red'>Always</option>
  <option value="tagged" color='blue'>Only when tagged</option>
  <option value="never" color='green'>Never</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$('#select').on('change', function(e){
var sel = "option[value="+this.value+"]";
$('#select').attr('style', 'background-color:'+ $(sel).attr('color'));
});
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/s9exy2rw/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using javascript.

Here's an example:

HTML

```
<body id="bg-img">
    <select id="backgroundOptions">
      <option value="always">Always</option>
      <option value="tagged">Only when tagged</option>
      <option value="never">Never</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
var elm = document.getElementById("backgroundOptions");
var bgOptions = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].value;
element.classList.add(bgOptions);
}
```

CSS

```
.always {background-color: red;}
.tagged {background-color: blue;}
.never {background-color: yellow;}
```